# Is there a way to test/debug my website for iPad Pro? (without an iPad Pro)

Tags: ios, wordpress, web, ipad

My web layout is causing errors on iPad Pro, with some things stretching or shrinking. When using chrome console set to iPad resolution it gets displayed correctly, so I cant rely on that. Any suggestion on how can I test it or what could be the problem?

I am using wordpress with divi, this specific page is a code module with HTML/JS/CSS. And I only have PC/Android

Answer (score 0):

Go To Chrome -> Press F12 -> Click the [Toggle Device Toolbar](http://prntscr.com/rqmlz9) (Located beside the word elements) -> From the dropdown menu you will be able to select iPad Pro

Maybe u can find temporary hosting web services? if chrome doesnt work for u such as netlify

Comment: As I said, setting iPad Pro on Chrome does not work because it gets displayed correctly, but in a real iPad it does not.

Comment: Hence I would recommend u to host your website on netlify to test. You can download virtual box to install mac os. Then from there, you can test with the emulator. So far virtual box is the only virtual machine that lets you download mac os

Answer (score 0):

In Safari Control+Command+R gives ui to test on multiple screen sizes, and if you are on Mac, just run the iOS Simulator from xcode and open your website in the simulator's safari

Comment: Can I install a reliable version of Safari on Windows? Or should I use a virtual machine with an iPad Pro OS? Sorry, I am not very used to Mac environment.

Comment: Safari for windows outdated, And AFAIK theres no virtual machine that supports or allows you to run iPadOS, so you will have to install macOS and test it